# UnboundLocalError UnboundLocalError: local variable 'username' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, flask

Can any one help me with this UnboundLocalError: local variable 'username' referenced before assignment

[image]

```
@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.form.get("username")
        password = request.form.get("password")

        username=db.execute("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username= :username", {"username":username}).fetchone()
        password=db.execute("SELECT username FROM users WHERE password= :password", {"password":password}).fetchone()

    if username is None:
        return render_template("error.html", message="Oops, something went wrong")
    else:
        return render_template("error.html", message="Error")

        return render_template("login.html")
```

And the Error pops up like

[image]

Comment: The second `if` statement needs to be indented inside the first one.

Comment: Please paste code and output as text - images can't be copied by us for experimentation.

Comment: @barmar could you show me how

Comment: I would love to, but I can't copy and paste your code from an image.

Comment: @barmar the code is know available

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty straightforward.If `method==POST` you define `username` but if method is not post `username` is not defined.Add `username = None` just after `def login`

Comment: i just done that but straight away it show the "None" rather than the login form

Comment: @Sadaf25 u r using get methid

Comment: @Sadaf25 u have defined what ur function should do if method is post....but what should your function do if method is not post

Answer (score 0):

The username check should be inside the first `if` block, because `username` is only assigned there.

```
@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.form.get("username")
        password = request.form.get("password")

        username=db.execute("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username= :username", {"username":username}).fetchone()
        password=db.execute("SELECT username FROM users WHERE password= :password", {"password":password}).fetchone()

        if username is None:
            return render_template("error.html", message="Oops, something went wrong")
        else:
            return render_template("error.html", message="Error")

    return render_template("login.html")
```

Also, the last `return` statement should not be inside the `if`, because it can never be reached because both branches of the inner `if/else` return.